# Unexpected pipe imported by the module 'AppModule'. Please add a @NgModule annotation

Tags: arrays, angular, loops, pipe

I have created Unique pipe for removing duplicate items from array and i have imported it into app.module.ts

Here is my code.

app.module.ts

```
import { UniquePipe } from './_pipe/uniquePipe';

@NgModule({
  imports: [BrowserModule, CommonModule, FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule, HttpClientModule, UniquePipe],
  // tslint:disable-next-line:max-line-length
  declarations: [ AppComponent, UniquePipe],
  exports: [UniquePipe ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ],
})
```

uniquePipe.ts

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import * as _ from 'lodash';


@Pipe({
  name: 'unique',
  pure: false
})
export class UniquePipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value: any): any {
    if (value !== undefined && value !== null) {
      return _.uniqBy(value, 'type');
    }
    return value;
  }
}
```

app.component.html

```
 <li class="nav-item" *ngFor="let items of list | unique">
      <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#list"> {{items.type}}</a>
    </li>
```

How can i resolve this issue

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pipes should be added only in `declarations`, so just remove your pipe from `imports`.